# Ubuntu occasionally downgrades Tomcat to the version from apt repository

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, downgrade

I'm using Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 20.04.

The apt installs Tomcat 9.0.31 which has a HTTPS-related bug preventing our web application from working well.

To fix the issue, I am manually updating Tomcat to a newer release (9.0.40), by downloading a ZIP archive from the Tomcat website and replacing the binary files of the older version in /usr/share/tomcat.

This approach worked until recently. Since March 2022 (approximately), I'm observing occasional downgrades of the installed Tomcat from 9.0.40 to 9.0.31!

I wonder how could I prevent that? Why the OS ever downgrades the software without any consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of holding back packages: with dpkg, apt, dselect, aptitude or Synaptic.
***dpkg***

Put a package on hold:

```
echo "<package-name> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Remove the hold:

```
echo "<package-name> install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Display the status of all your packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Display the status of a single package:

```
dpkg --get-selections <package-name>
```

Show all packages on hold:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "\<hold$"
```

***apt***

Hold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

Show all packages on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

***dselect***

With dselect, enter the [S]elect screen, find the package you wish to hold in its present state and press = or H. The changes will take effect immediately after exiting the [S]elect screen.

The following approaches are limited in that locking/holding a package within aptitude or synaptic doesn't affect apt-get/apt.

***aptitude***

Hold a package:

```
sudo aptitude hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo aptitude unhold <package-name>
```

***Locking with Synaptic Package Manager***

Go to Synaptic Package Manager (System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager).

Click the search button and type the package name.

When you find the package, select it and go to the Package menu and select Lock Version.

That package will now not show in the update manager and will not be updated.